# select into loop statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Pls I need help inserting the result of one query into another query and returning the result like a regular select statement

the first query is:

```
select distinct due_dt 
from  ln_acct_repmnt_event
order by 1 asc
```

then i want to pass due_dt into a second query which should loop for as many records at the first query returns:

```
select TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR') as date1,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS YEAR, 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS MONTH
FROM dual;
```

and I want the result returned.

Pls, any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a loop here ?  just use the second query but replace the `from dual` to `from  ln_acct_repmnt_event`. Or do you need something else ?

Comment: Probably the construction you are looking for is a [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-25917214-FD91-499D-AB39-CE21484AB167). Whether or not it's a good approach here depends on what you are trying to do with it. As @Sujitmohanty30 said, in the example you gave it would be better to combine the two into a single query without needing any loops.

Comment: Side observation: why are you applying TO_DATE to DUE_DT?  DUE_DT should already be of data type DATE.  If it is not, that is Design Fail Number One.  And if it IS (as it should be) already a DATE, the applying TO_DATE will force an implied TO_CHAR first, and a high risk of NLS_DATE_FORMAT mis-match.  Also, the RRRR format was intended as a _temporary_ fix for Y2K -- _twenty years ago_!  Banish it from your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you need:

```
WITH duedatesdistinct
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT due_dt
         FROM   ln_acct_repmnt_event)
SELECT due_dt,
       TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')                     AS date1,
       EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR'))  AS year,
       EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS month
FROM   duedatesdistinct
ORDER  BY 1 ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the date logic in the first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR') as date1,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS YEAR, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS MONTH
FROM ln_acct_repmnt_event
ORDR BY 1 ASC;
```

If you *really* want, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR') as date1,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS YEAR, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS MONTH
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT due_dt
      FROM ln_acct_repmnt_event
     ) a
ORDR BY 1 ASC;
```

But the subquery is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a loop, Using the for loop and combine your query like this.

```
For rec in (SELECT DISTINCT 
TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR') as date1,
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS YEAR, 
 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(due_dt, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) AS MONTH
 FROM ln_acct_repmnt_event
 ORDR BY 1 ASC)
 Loop
  -- the logic which need to be written
  End loop;
```